# Displaying a jssor slider at the top?

Tags: html, jssor

I cannot seem to find the answer on here for putting a jssor slider right at the top of a page. It is by default set to:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
```

It works if I use top:-100px; but that only works for some resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can insert the slider in a container, you can specify css to position the container.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0...">
        <!-- insert jssor slider here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would be the obvious place to put it :) But it doesn't work in positioning it at the top. I don't just mean somewhere near the top of the page. I mean "top: 0" positioning.

Comment: I appreciate your effort a lot (and I really like the sliders), and I will return to upvote as soon as I have enough points to do so. Unfortunately, that also doesn't work for me :(